# The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10.1" has not been registered.; 42000

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services Project. In the Data Source View I have a Named Query which references a single Data Source containing three tables. The Project processes successfully and the cube can be browsed.

I recently added a second Data Source to the Data Source View and linked a table to the original Named Query.

When I try to process the project, I get the message:

OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10.1" has not been registered.; 42000.

The Connection String for both Data Sources uses SQLNCLI10.1

Comment: Would like to hear if there was any resolution. I have the identical scenario.

Answer (score 0):

What is the connection string used to connect the Data source, it should on similar lines of: Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security="";Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW;Data Source=MyServer;Initial File Name="";Server SPN=""

The SQLNCLI10.1 is for SQL 2008 and higher version, you may also check and download from SQL 2008 R2 feature pack and reinstall on the server. SO you can try edit the Data Source(s) for the database and switch from the SQLNCLI.1 provider to the SQLNCLI10.1 Native Client provider.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server *"Native"* OLE DB Driver known as "SQLNCLI10" does not ship with Windows. It shipped with SQL Server 2008.

This means you will have to manually install it on the machine that wants to connect to the database.

Other **OLE DB** providers for SQL Server:

- `SQLOLEDB`: Ships with every version of Windows
- `SQLNCLI`: Shipped with SQL Server 2005; must be manually installed on client machines *(not recommended)*
- `SQLNCLI10`: Shipped with SQL Server 2008; must be manually installed on client machines *(not recommended)*
- `SQLNCLI11`: Shipped with SQL Server 2012; must be manually installed on client machines *(not recommended)*
- `MSOLEDBSQL`: Shipped with SQL Server 2017 and newer; must be manually installed on client machines. Supports SQL Server 2005 and newer.